# create share menu and add images

Tags: iphone, image, menu, share

I've two questions for you, which i can't solve:

1) How do I create a menu like this --> [image: Example]
<sub>(source: [momolog.com](http://www.momolog.com/media/img/manual/share_menu.jpg))</sub>
.
2) How can I add multiple images like the iApp named HotBook do?
.
Thanks in advance for your help.
Sean

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but this may help others who come across the page...

For #1, that's a UIActionSheet. You can instantiate it with this:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"On Facebook", @"On Twitter", nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet release];
```

Note that your UIViewController must conform to the UIActionSheetDelegate protocol.